# Min-height causes empty space on Facebook Comments plugin

Tags: css, plugins, height, facebook-comments

I have encountered a pretty annoying problem. I am setting up Facebook Comments plugin on my new site, and for some reason it has a min-height:160px, which creates a huge empty space at the bottom of the plugin when there are no comments.

This is really annoying and doesn't go with my design at all.
I already tried overriding the min-height on my own templates .css file with !important, but that didn't seem to do a thing.

Look at the screenshot above to see what I'm talking about.

[image]
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you edit the min-height in the element style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't style that Facebook plugin because the iframe is not on the same domain!**

You can style iframes from the same domain by inserting ca link tag using javascript. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) for more details.